# Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in laravel session foreach

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Im practicing laravel and right now Im in the session topic

this is my controller

```
public function set(Request $request){
   $product = Product::findOrFail($request->input('id'));
   session()->put('product', $product);
   return redirect()->route('cart');
 }
```

when i tried to echo the`{{session()->get('product')}}` on my blade it produce an output of

```
{
  "id":9,
  "name":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
  "description":"Proin pretium, mauris id convallis tempus, lorem enim tincidunt nulla, vel pharetra sapien odio eget ligula. Sed maximus, massa sit amet condimentum bibendum, nisi ante vestibulum ipsum, ut ornare justo lorem mollis justo.",
  "price":"22.21",
  "cover_image":"JRwg9TSKTvUTvuij.jpg",
  "created_at":"2018-07-20 03:47:57",
  "updated_at":"2018-07-20 03:47:57"
}
```

but when i tried  to use foreach on it by using

```
@foreach(session()->get('product') as $key)
        {{$key->id}}
@endforeach
```

it shows an error of `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object`

can someone guide me why I'm I getting this error thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are iterating through your single object but what you seem to need to do is:

```
{{ session()->get('product')->id }}
```

If you want to loop then you can do:

```
@foreach (session()->get('product')->toArray() as $key => $value) 
     {{ $key }}: {{ $value }}
@endforeach
```

This will result in:

```
id: 9
name: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
description: Proin pretium, mauris id convallis tempus, lorem enim tincidunt nulla, vel pharetra sapien odio eget ligula. Sed maximus, massa sit amet condimentum bibendum, nisi ante vestibulum ipsum, ut ornare justo lorem mollis justo.
price: 22.21
cover_image: JRwg9TSKTvUTvuij.jpg
created_at: 2018-07-20 03:47:57
updated_at: 2018-07-20 03:47:57
```

However, just as a sidenote this is bad practice because your coupling your view with a session entry. Ideally your view would just take a product object as a view parameters and use that directly. That way you can pass it that object either from the session or from a database query.

Comment: hey can i ask a question

Comment: @Beginner You could

Comment: Btw sir Im doing a feature of add to cart just like in here https://shop.laracom.net/ am I doing it the right way ? how come on the example after i refresh the page the cart number is not resetting it is still the same. Thats what exactly what i want to achieve sir

Comment: so my plan is to just store it on a session and just loop throught it in view.

Comment: The session will persist for a specific user. If you don't want that then use `session()->flash` to keep it only for a single request. However, as I said you should determine what you send to your view via the controller and not have the view directly access the session. Something like `return view(...)->with('product', session()->get('product')` in your controller and using `$product` in the view. If on the other hand you want to store multiple products in the session then use an array e.g. `session()->put('products', [])` and then append to that and store it again.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get single value from an object you can get like this.

```
{{ session()->get('product')->id }}
```

Or If you wish to print all data, First you have to convert object into an array then use foreach.

```
@foreach (session()->get('product')->toArray() as $key => $value) 
 {{ $key }}: {{ $value }} </br> 
@endforeach
```

Comment: what if i use toJson() instead of toArray()

Comment: how do i get a single value from an object in view @Shaan Ansari

Comment: Like this {{ session()->get('product')->id }}

Comment: im using this return view('cart.index')->with('product',session()->get('product')->toJson()); how can i print it on blade template

Comment: Why do you want to use toJson() the data is allready in json format. if you want to retrieve data by using loop like foreach you have convert it into an array().

Comment: You did not pass the session data along with view you can retrieve session directly in a view.

Comment: what do you mean i didnt pass session data

Comment: Why do we use session to use the value in across the project. Just put data into session as you doing in controller, and get this session in project (model/view/controller).

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way :

```
@foreach(session()->get('product') as $key)
    {{$key['id']}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: By getting object data in an array format you didn't get anything :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to iterate an object. When you try to do this you get the public properties from the object. In your example `$key` is one of those properties, not the model itself.

When you `echo` `{{ }}` a Model `__toString` gets called which returns the serialized model as json.

If you want that model's `id` you can just grab it like normal. `session('product')->id`

If you want you can serialize the Model to an array:

```
foreach ($model->toArray() as $key => $value) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: but is there a way i can loop through with it? i just want to display all the data from session

Comment: loop through what ... its a model, what do you want to display?

Comment: all this {
  "id":9,
  "name":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
  "description":"Proin pretium, mauris id convallis tempus, lorem enim tincidunt nulla, vel pharetra sapien odio eget ligula. Sed maximus, massa sit amet condimentum bibendum, nisi ante vestibulum ipsum, ut ornare justo lorem mollis justo.",
  "price":"22.21",
  "cover_image":"JRwg9TSKTvUTvuij.jpg",
  "created_at":"2018-07-20 03:47:57",
  "updated_at":"2018-07-20 03:47:57"
}

Comment: Then just show `session()->get('product')` why you want to loop

Comment: those are the attributes of the model  [Laravel Docs 5.6 - Eloquent - Serialization - Serializing to Arrays](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-arrays)

Comment: sir @lagbox can i ask a question